# Where Does Django Store It's Test Databse

Tags: python, django

When using an SQLite database where does Django store the database that it uses when running tests?

Is there way to define this path?

I would like to be able to manually look at the contents of the test database following each test.

The command `python manage.py test --keepdb` is supposed to keep the database, which it does, but I cannot seem to find where this database is stored.

The dev database is stored in the root of the project but the test database is not found there.

Comment: The test database should be stored in the same place as ORIGINAL_DATABASE_NAME_Test, is it not?

Comment: Thats's what i would have thought, but its not seeming to be there on mine. @Ares

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the docs:

> When using SQLite, the tests will use an in-memory database by default (i.e., the database will be created in memory, bypassing the filesystem entirely!). The TEST dictionary in DATABASES offers a number of settings to configure your test database. For example, if you want to use a different database name, specify NAME in the TEST dictionary for any given database in DATABASES.

for more info see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Comment: Thank you, that would explain the lack of database file.